# Building binary packets on C#

Tags: c#, binary, packet

I'm trying to build a packet structured as:

HEADER OP

Where HEADER size is 4 bytes, and contains total packet length.
OP size is 2 bytes, and contains an integer.

For example, i'm trying to send as OP "3".
So packet should become {2, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0}
Where 2, 0, 0, 0 is header and 3, 0 is OP (padded to the left)

Comment: OK.  What is your specific question about that?

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm trying to build it using C# but i have no idea on how to convert data to bytes and above all padding data

Comment: Your first step is to start with a *detailed specification* of the packet structure.  Do you have that?

Comment: Well all i know, as written above, is that packets are structured before with an header (4 bytes), OP (2 bytes), and if necessary by packet type possible data. In my case i only need to send HEADER + OP, trying to send via Stream.Write the packet i wrote above ({2, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0}) it works, so i need to build this packet only using the OP, so the code will have to understand total packet length (in this case, 2 since OP is 2 bytes) and build the header

Comment: I'll see if I can cobble together an example below.

Comment: You mention packets yet you also mention streams. These are contradictory statements. If you care about packets, you're usually talking about UDP, which is not a stream protocol. TCP is a stream protocol, but you don't have control over packets. Is it possible that you mean "frame" every time you've said "packet"? If so, *that* might make sense. If you're describing frames in a streaming protocol, then : sure!

Comment: Well i'm not very prepared about TCP/UDP context. I'm trying to code a Client in C# which communicates with an already coded by 3rd party server and it's through TCP connection, server calls data as "Packets" so i tought it's name was that

Comment: Frame protocol code is pretty deep, and is a huge topic. There's also about 6 different technologies that you could use to do the same thing here, depending on your needs. I wrote an extensive series of blogs covering how to do this with "pipelines" (the new IO API) - start is here, but part 3 probably has the most relevant code samples for you: https://blog.marcgravell.com/2018/07/pipe-dreams-part-1.html

Comment: @Alessandro fair enough - if we're talking TCP, then yes it sounds like we're talking about "frames" - subtle and possibly pedantic, but all these terms have specific meanings and it helps everyone to use the same ones. I already want to have a quiet word (or several noisy words) with whoever wrote that server documentation :)

Answer (score 1):

You'll need the following two methods to perform conversions to and from byte arrays.  I am assuming this is all Little Endian.

```
/// <summary>
/// Converts the supplied object to a byte array.
/// </summary>
public static byte[] ToByteArray(object obj)
{
    int len = Marshal.SizeOf(obj);
    byte[] arr = new byte[len];
    IntPtr ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(len);
    Marshal.StructureToPtr(obj, ptr, true);
    Marshal.Copy(ptr, arr, 0, len);
    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr);
    return arr;
}

/// <summary>
/// Maps the supplied byte array onto a structure of the specified type.
/// </summary>
public static T ToStructure<T>(byte[] byteArray)
{
    GCHandle h = GCHandle.Alloc(byteArray, GCHandleType.Pinned);
    T result = (T)Marshal.PtrToStructure(h.AddrOfPinnedObject(), typeof(T));
    h.Free();
    return result;
}
```

Now you just need a structure that will hold your data.  It will look something like this:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
public struct PacketHeader
{
    public UInt32 HEADER;
    public UInt16 OP;
}
```

And then all you have to do is populate an instance of `PacketHeader` with data, and convert it to a byte array like this:

```
var packetHeader = new PacketHeader
{
    HEADER=2,
    OP=3
};

var bytes = ToByteArray(packetHeader);
```

To reverse the process:

```
var packetHeader p FromByteArray<PacketHeader>(bytes);
```

Comment: Doing this via struct seems like a mis-step to me, but it would work for fixed-size cases, CPU-endianness permitting. If you're going to do that, though, there are much more direct ways of moving the data around, especially now that we have span-T which allows direct conversion between primitives including to/from byte-spans. Also, even if you keep the Marshal approach, unsafe/fixed over the existing buffer s preferable to an unmanaged alloc

Comment: Thank you, it is very clear and looks like it's "almost" doing its job. Only one thing: OP output is 3, 0, 0, 0 (in my case) but it should be 2 bytes (3, 0). Do you know what i should edit?

Comment: Make sure that OP is of type `UInt16`.

Comment: Right but including the header, OP should be 2 bytes long only, total output of your code is: 2, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0

Comment: Hmm, I'll have to check it when I get home.  Sounds like it's aligning on 32 bit boundaries.  In the meantime, you can just strip off the last two bytes before you transmit.

Comment: Okay, thank you. I also tried changing OP to byte (which should be uint8) to see if something could change but nothing, still 4 bytes

Comment: Another thing (sorry if i'm writing too much in comments), i see you are populating header data manually, but in case i'm going to build bigger packets, what if header data should be calculated by code?